# Problems to bind port / interface

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos-big-sur

After reinstalling a package that is used to host web-based experiments (psiturk) and runs on python I'm facing issues with the binding of a port to the interface which results in the server being blocked. I've tried using different ports they are all immediately blocked. It gives me the following warning when trying to start the server (no other error messages or server log):

`Now serving on http://localhost:22363 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py:1023: RuntimeWarning: line buffering (buffering=1) isn't supported in binary mode, the default buffer size will be used return io.open(fd, *args, **kwargs)`

Could this be related to a mac security issue? Or did something go wrong with the installation (I had some issues with multiple python versions)?

Some more info: recently updated to bigsur, psiturk running on python 3.8

Comment: This has nothing to do with port binding. The package opened a stream in binary mode, but it's trying to use an option that only applies to text mode streams.

Comment: Maybe this is related to upgrading Python.